# Travel with violin Amtrak from Trenton NJ to Lancaster PA

Tags: amtrak

Does anyone have experience taking musical instruments out of Trenton? My violin case just measures outside the sizing given on amtrak.com for medium-sized cases. What I want to avoid is getting to the train station, and then being forced to buy a second ticket because my case is two inches too long (all the other dimensions easily fit). Does anyone know how strict they may be about allowing it? It seems that I really shouldn't have a problem with the overhead space and such, and as far as I know, it's not a particularly busy train. I'll also be going from Indianapolis back to Trenton non-stop. I've done a lot of reading so far about cellos on Amtrak, but any violin-specific advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, it's not on this list of exceptions so you should be good! http://maphappy.org/2015/03/things-that-will-get-you-kicked-off-amtrak/

Not entirely sure how comprehensive this list is but hopefully you were able to carry your violin safely with you on your trip!